# React state, remove item in array after a while

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm facing a problem, I have a React state which is an array.

When an item is added to the array with setState, I would like to delete it after for example five seconds.

Something like :

```
const {messages, setMessages} = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setMessages(arr => arr.splice(i, 1))
    }, 5000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
})
```

Where `i` is the index of the item to delete.

As a concrete example: I click every second in a button, this add an item to the array.  After 5 seconds, the first item is deleted.
After 6 seconds, the second item is deleted.
etc...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set each item in the array as an object with a `timeRemaining` property and then use `setInterval` to reduce the time every second until it eventually hits 0, at which point you would delete the item.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const interval = setInterval(()=>{
    setMessages(prev=>prev.filter(i=>i.timeRemaining>0).map((item)=>{
      return {
        ...item, timeRemaining: item.timeRemaining - 1
      }
    }))
  },1000)
  return ()=> clearInterval(interval)
},[])
```

Comment: It works pretty well thank you! the only problem is that it removes the elements of the table starting from the last added.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.splice` mutates the array in place, meaning the `messages` state array reference never changes and React bails out of rerendering.

[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or
> replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

[Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the `Object.is` comparison algorithm.)

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to shallow copy the previous `messages` array into a new reference, except for the element at the specified matching index.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setMessages(arr => arr.filter((_, index) => index !== i)) // *
  }, 5000);

  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, []); // <-- don't forget dependency array!
```

* assumes `i` is defined in scope